# The OR operator is not returning true

Tags: php

I have a problem with an OR operator here's the code:

```
    $Year;
    if ($IDCode[0] = 1 || 2) {
        $Year = "18" . $IDCode[1] . $IDCode[2] ;
    }

    else if ($IDCode[0] = 5 || 6) {
        $Year = "20" . $IDCode[1] . $IDCode[2] ;
    }
    echo $Year;
```

So essentially a user enter's his IDcode
example `50005120342`

dont mind the other numbers.

Essentially what I want is that IF the first number is 1 OR 2 it SHOULD output 18 + the other numbers same for if it's 5 OR 6 it should output 20.
BUT in my case it is ALWAYS showing 18 and I can't figure out why.

EDIT:
Apologies, due to frequent work with C#, the logic there doesn't apply here.
Sorry again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple conditions are combined this way.

```
if ($IDCode[0] == 1 || $IDKood[0] == 2) {
    $Year = "18" . $IDCode[1] . $IDCode[2] ;
}

else if ($IDKood[0] == 5 ||  $IDKood[0] == 6) {
    $Year = "20" . $IDCode[1] . $IDCode[2] ;
}
```

In `$IDCode[0] = 1 || 2`, `1` is assigned to the first element for `$IDCode` and `1 || 2` evaluated. This is always truthy.

Answer (score 0):

the condition should be:

$IDCode[0] == 1|| $IDCode[0] == 2

Answer (score 0):

You should write full condition for a multiple combination

```
$IDCode = "50005120342";
if ($IDCode[0] == 1 || $IDCode[0] == 2) {
   $Year = "18" . $IDCode[1] . $IDCode[2] ;
}

else if ($IDCode[0] == 5 || $IDCode[0]==6) {
   $Year = "20" . $IDCode[1] . $IDCode[2] ;
}
echo $Year;
```

For your second condition `else if ($IDKood[0] = 5 || 6)`, though the variable was wrongly written as `IDKood`, the program evaluates `$IDCode[0] = 5|| 6` as true, cause it was setting the variable and which is true always.